# Why doesn't my simple C macro work?

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor-directive

I want to make a simple macro that calls printf() twice like this

```
#ifdef ENABLE_DEBUGPRINTF
#define DEBUGPRINTF(msg) printf("At sim_time = %f:", sim_time); printf(msg);
#else
#define DEBUGPRINTF(msg)  //evalutes to nothing
#endif
```

Now when I call

```
DEBUGPRINTF("Processed event type: %d with value %f\n", id, data)
```

It prints the first part "At sime_time = ... " correctly but the latter part where it says "Processed events ... " prints the value for id and data incorrectly.

Meanwhile

```
printf("Processed event type: %d with value %f\n", id, data);
```

Prints the values correctly.

When I try executing it by writing exactly out what I thought the macro would evaluate to, I have.

```
printf("At sim_time = %f:", sim_time); printf("Processed event type: %d with value %f\n", id, data);
```

This prints everything correctly! So why isn't my macro evaluating to this?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths D'oh of course. Sorry, I'm not used to pre-processor directives.  For some reason I imaged everything inside the parenthesis would be contained in 'msg'.

Comment: Unrelated, but it's best to put braces around a multi-instruction macro like this: `#define DEBUGPRINTF(msg, id, data) { etc... }`. Otherwise you could get some surprises when, for example, the macro is used after a `if`.

Comment: @user1320881: That still will result in wrong code, e.g. in an `if` statement.  The common way to do it correctly is wrap into a `do .. while ( 0 )` dummy-loop. Every modern compiler will recognise this pattern and optimise-aways the loop.

Comment: @Olaf: In this case, since the `printf` calls are expressions, it's even better to separate them with a comma operator and enclose the whole thing in parentheses (and drop the semicolons). The `do ... while(0)` trick let's you use the macro anywhere a statement is expected, but if the expansion is an expression it's even more flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want and are using the full flexibility of a regular `printf`, what you want is a macro with a `variadic` argument:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_DEBUGPRINTF
#define DEBUGPRINTF(msg...) \
    printf("At sim_time = %f:", sim_time); printf(msg);
#else
#define DEBUGPRINTF(msg...)  /*evalutes to nothing*/
#endif
```

---

I've done this many times before and I recommend encapsulating with `do { } while (0)`:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_DEBUGPRINTF
#define DEBUGPRINTF(msg...) \
    do { \
        printf("At sim_time = %f:", sim_time); \
        printf(msg); \
    } while (0)
#else
#define DEBUGPRINTF(msg...)  //evalutes to nothing
#endif
```

This allows you to do something like:

```
if (showit)
    DEBUGPRINTF("hit the showit point -- showit=%d\n",showit);
```

Thus, the code that uses the macro doesn't have to know that it's actually two statements [or none]

---

**UPDATE:**

> `DEBUGPRINTF(msg...)` is not standard compliant, but some legacy compiler extension. You missed a comma before the ellipsis.

Perhaps, but, personally, I still prefer it, and have been using it in production code for 10+ years.

However, here are some resources for those that might wish to use the alternative ways:

1. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro

Comment: `DEBUGPRINTF(msg...)` is not standard compliant, but some legacy compiler extension. You missed a comma before the ellipsis.

Answer (score 2):

You declare `DEBUGPRINTF` as taking one argument, but then you pass it three, so of course it's not working as you'd expect.

`msg` is just `"Processed event type: %d with value %f\n"` in your first example, and your second `printf()` call is just pulling garbage for the `%d` and the `%f`, because your macro never tells it anything about `id` or `data` and so they never get passed to `printf()`.

You want something like:

```
#define DEBUGPRINTF(msg, id, data) printf("At sim_time = %f:", sim_time); printf(msg, id, data);
```

or, if you need something more flexible, to play around with variadic macros.

Comment: This still causes trouble if used as the body of a statement like `if`.

Answer (score -3):

Use a double ( nested) definition:

```
#define FIRST         printf("…")
#define DEBUGMSG(msg) FIRST;printf(msg)
```

This has one argument in definition, and one argument in implementation.

Comment: This does nothing more than what the OP already has. It does not resolve the OP's actual question at all. If you try `DEBUGPRINTF("Processed event type: %d with value %f\n", id, data)` as the OP wants then you will find your solution will fail in exactly the same way as the OP is experiencing.