# quick and easy way to comment out multi lined print statements

Tags: c, shell

Is there a quick and easy way to comment out multi lined print statements? Something like this? I have a ton of printf statements that I use for debugging that are spread out across my program. I would like to comment out every printf() except the ones that contain "ACCEPT" or "Reject". I have several hundred of them but they are scattered between important code so I can't use block comments.

```
                   lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter++;
                    printf("3387 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s \n", 
                    strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
                    printf("3389 lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d \n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
                }
                strcpy(array_id1, strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
                integer_match_flag = 0; 
                float_match_flag = 0;
            }
        }
        if(keywords_match_flag1 != 1)
        {
            lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter++;
        }
        cmp_str9 = strcmp("return", strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter ]);
        printf("4006 lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d \n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
        printf("4007 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s \n", 
        strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
        //int
        if(cmp_str9 == 0)
        {
            printf("3402 checking return stuff \n");
            return_match_flag = 1;
            lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter++;
            get_function_type_for_proper_return(symbol_table_functions, type,id, 
                                     scope_char, symbol_table_functions_counter, function_type_for_proper_return);
            printf("3407 lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d \n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
            printf("3408 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s \n", 
            strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
            printf("3410 function_type_for_proper_return %s \n", function_type_for_proper_return);
```

Comment: Maybe you should use a different function name (or a macro name) in future — so that you have `#define DEBUG_PRINT(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)` etc.  See [C `#define` macro for debug printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing/1644898#1644898) and related posts for more complex ways to do that.  Which editor do you use?  How many files like this do you have to process?

Comment: You really need to show some example `printf()` statements that should be retained.  AFAICS, all the examples in your code fragment should be commented out.  But it would help to have some examples that should be kept too — it is easy enough to comment out every `printf()` statement (a little bit of not-quite-elementary `sed` will do that: `sed -e '/printf(.*);/ { s%^%//%; n; }' -e '/printf(/,/);/ s%^%//%' `).  But preserving the 'ACCEPT' and 'Reject' lines makes it harder.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have one file with 5k lines of code. I have lots of functions not crazy enough to do everything in main. I use notepad ++ in windows and vim in linux/unix. Do you have any favorite text editors? Ok I can always uncomment them. I have like 10 lines i want to keep and hundreds of lines I want to comment out.

Comment: I use `vim`, usually even when I work on Windows (which is rather seldom).  The `sed` script I showed will do a decent job on commenting all the `printf()` lines — even multi-line ones — out.  It can be confused, but you probably won't confuse it.  If you had `);` inside a string on the second or subsequent line of a `printf()`, but that wasn't the last line, the script would stop commenting lines too soon.  But that's pretty implausible.

Answer (score 2):

Since your base code is `C` and the `printf` statements are [obviously] for debug, please allow me to suggest an alternative approach.

Change the `printf` used for debug into (e.g.) `DEBUGPRINTF`. This is a CPP macro that can be compiled to something with a compiler command line option like `-DDEBUG`. See my recent answer here: [Why doesn't my simple C macro work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378880/why-doesnt-my-simple-c-macro-work/36379322#36379322) for a more formal description.

*Side note:* I wrote this current answer before noticing Jonathan's comment about doing it in a similar way.

Thus, you only need to do the change *once* and can turn debug printing on and off at the flip of a compile option. I've been using this technique for decades and it's served me quite well.

*Note:* You'll still need to do the global edit *once* to get this.

Here's a perl script that will do that (invoke via `./script < input > output`):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# convert debug printf's

master(@ARGV);
exit(0);

# master -- master control
sub master
{

    while ($bf = <STDIN>) {
        chomp($bf);

        if ($bf =~ /^\s*printf[(]/) {
            doprintf($bf);
            next
        }

        print($bf,"\n");
    }
}

# doprintf -- process printf
sub doprintf
{
    my($bf) = @_;
    my($allowflg);

    $allowflg = ($bf =~ /ACCEPT|Reject/);
    unless ($allowflg) {
        $bf =~ s/printf/DEBUGPRINTF/;
    }

    print($bf,"\n");

    while (1) {
        last if ($bf =~ /;\s*$/);

        $bf = <STDIN>;
        last unless (defined($bf));
        chomp($bf);

        print($bf,"\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `$bf =~ /^\s*printf\s*[(]/` for the nuts that put a space before the opening paren?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, IIRC, that's the "GNU" coding style, which I personally despise. My coding style, developed over many years, looks remarkably like the linux kernel style in `Documentation/CodingStyle`. From that: _"First off, I'd suggest printing out a copy of the GNU coding standards, and NOT read it.  Burn them, it's a great symbolic gesture."_

Answer (score 1):

A multiline solution with GNU sed :

```
sed '/ACCEPT\|Reject/!{/^[\t ]*printf(/{:a;s/^/\/\/ &/;/;/!{n;Ta}}}' file.c
```

Exluding all lines containing `ACCEPT` or `Reject`, it comments out all lines starting with `printf` and ending with `;`.

If no ending `;` is found on the `printf` line, it loops over and comments out  subsequent lines until a `;` is found.

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick, simple, effective, over-enthusiastic

It is fairly simple to comment out all the `printf()` lines in a file with `sed`, even multi-line ones, if you use:

```
sed -e '/printf(.*);/ { s%^%//%; n; }' -e '/printf(/,/);/ s%^%//%'
```

On the sample lines, this yields:

```
                   lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter++;
//                    printf("3387 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s \n", 
//                    strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
//                    printf("3389 lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d \n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
                }
                strcpy(array_id1, strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
                integer_match_flag = 0; 
                float_match_flag = 0;
            }
        }
        if(keywords_match_flag1 != 1)
        {
            lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter++;
        }
        cmp_str9 = strcmp("return", strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter ]);
//        printf("4006 lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d \n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
//        printf("4007 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s \n", 
//        strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
        //int
        if(cmp_str9 == 0)
        {
//            printf("3402 checking return stuff \n");
            return_match_flag = 1;
            lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter++;
            get_function_type_for_proper_return(symbol_table_functions, type,id, 
                                     scope_char, symbol_table_functions_counter, function_type_for_proper_return);
//            printf("3407 lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d \n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
//            printf("3408 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s \n", 
//            strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
//            printf("3410 function_type_for_proper_return %s \n", function_type_for_proper_return);
```

However, if any of the `printf()` statements contained `ACCEPT` or `Reject`, those lines would be commented out too.  Given that you have hundreds of lines that should be commented out and a few (order of ten) that should not be commented, it is probably easiest to undo the incorrectly commented out lines.

#### Refined, complex, effective

I got an alternative working, and it handles `printf` statements with `ACCEPT` and `Reject` in the first line correctly.  It won't spot those words in the second or subsequent lines of a `printf` statement.

```
${SED:-sed} \
    -e '/printf(.*ACCEPT.*);/ b' \
    -e '/printf(.*Reject.*);/ b' \
    -e '/printf(.*);/ { s%^%//%; b
        }' \
    -e '/printf(.*ACCEPT/, /);/ b' \
    -e '/printf(.*Reject/, /);/ b' \
    -e '/printf(/, /);/ s%^%//%' \
    frag.c
```

The odd newline is need to placate BSD (Mac OS X) `sed`.

Input:

```
                   lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter++;
                    printf("3387 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n", 
                    strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
                    printf("3389 lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
                }
                strcpy(array_id1, strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
                integer_match_flag = 0; 
                float_match_flag = 0;
            }
        }
        if(keywords_match_flag1 != 1)
        {
            lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter++;
        }
        cmp_str9 = strcmp("return", strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter ]);

        printf("4006 lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
        wimbol();
        printf("ACCEPT: lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
        wimbol();
printf("Testing ACCEPT %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
        wimbol();
        printf("Reject: lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
        wimbol();
        printf("4007 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n", 
                strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
        wimbol();
        printf("Reject: strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n", 
                strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
        wimbol();
        printf("ACCEPT: strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n", 
                strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
        wimbol();

        printf("4006 lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
        printf("ACCEPT: lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
printf("Testing ACCEPT %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
        printf("Reject: lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
        printf("4007 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n", 
                strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
        printf("Reject: strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n", 
                strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
        printf("ACCEPT: strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n", 
                strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);

        //int
        if(cmp_str9 == 0)
        {
            printf("3402 checking return stuff\n");
            return_match_flag = 1;
            lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter++;
            get_function_type_for_proper_return(symbol_table_functions, type,id, 
                                     scope_char, symbol_table_functions_counter, function_type_for_proper_return);
            printf("3407 lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
            printf("3408 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n", 
            strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
            printf("3410 function_type_for_proper_return %s\n", function_type_for_proper_return);
```

Output:

```
                   lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter++;
//                    printf("3387 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n", 
//                    strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
//                    printf("3389 lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
                }
                strcpy(array_id1, strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
                integer_match_flag = 0; 
                float_match_flag = 0;
            }
        }
        if(keywords_match_flag1 != 1)
        {
            lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter++;
        }
        cmp_str9 = strcmp("return", strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter ]);

//        printf("4006 lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
        wimbol();
        printf("ACCEPT: lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
        wimbol();
printf("Testing ACCEPT %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
        wimbol();
        printf("Reject: lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
        wimbol();
//        printf("4007 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n", 
//                strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
        wimbol();
        printf("Reject: strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n", 
                strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
        wimbol();
        printf("ACCEPT: strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n", 
                strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
        wimbol();

//        printf("4006 lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
        printf("ACCEPT: lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
printf("Testing ACCEPT %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
        printf("Reject: lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
//        printf("4007 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n", 
//                strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
        printf("Reject: strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n", 
                strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
        printf("ACCEPT: strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n", 
                strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);

        //int
        if(cmp_str9 == 0)
        {
//            printf("3402 checking return stuff\n");
            return_match_flag = 1;
            lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter++;
            get_function_type_for_proper_return(symbol_table_functions, type,id, 
                                     scope_char, symbol_table_functions_counter, function_type_for_proper_return);
//            printf("3407 lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter %d\n", lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
//            printf("3408 strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter] %s\n", 
//            strings_line_tokens[lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
//            printf("3410 function_type_for_proper_return %s\n", function_type_for_proper_return);
```

I was previously having some issues; I am kicking myself for some of them (sequencing — it is crucial to deal with all the single-line `printf()` statements before starting on the multi-line ones).  There's a more subtle difference between `b` (jump to end of script) and `n` (read next line), which is also crucial.

I'm testing with BSD `sed` on Mac OS X 10.11.4, JFTR.  GNU `sed` doesn't require the extra newline in the script.

Answer (score 0):

using `sed` is a oneway conversion and requires a separate step before compiling.

A much better method is:

when debugging use the compiler parameter:

```
-DDEBUG=1
```

when not debugging use the compiler parameter:

```
-DDEBUG=0
```

Then, in the code use:

```
if( DEBUG )
{
     // your debugging printf()
    printf( ,,,, );
}
```

Then when the code must be certified, for instance to RTCA DO-178B there is no difference in the source code between the tested code and the released code.